# Row composable not taking up the full width of parent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-jetpack-compose-row

I have a shopping list item composable that is not taking up the entire width of the parent, as you can see below with the red border. I want it to be flush against the parent's edge. And why is there some space or padding just before the checkbox? What needs to be modified?

[image]

**Composable**

```
@Composable
fun ShoppingListScreenItem(
    itemName: String,
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().border(2.dp, Red),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Checkbox(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
            checked = checked,
            onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            text = itemName
        )
    }
}
```

**Parent Composable**

```
@Composable
fun ShoppingListScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    shoppingListScreenViewModel: ShoppingListScreenViewModel
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val name = stringResource(id = R.string.item_name)
    val nameError = stringResource(id = R.string.item_IsNameError)
    val category = stringResource(id = R.string.item_category)
    val categoryError = stringResource(id = R.string.item_IsCategoryError)

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val allItems =
        shoppingListScreenViewModel.shoppingListItemsState.value?.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "AppBar") },
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                navigationIcon = if (navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                    {
                        IconButton(onClick = { navController.navigateUp() }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                contentDescription = "Back"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    null
                }
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue("ShowAddItemDialog", true)
                },
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                contentColor = Color.White
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "")
            }
        },
        // Defaults to false
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = false,
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                    vertical = 8.dp,
                    horizontal = 8.dp
                )
            ) {
                //todo change it to non null
                items(allItems!!) { item ->
                    ShoppingListScreenItem(
                        itemName = item?.name!!,
                        checked = item.isInCart
                    ) { isChecked ->
                        scope.launch {
                            shoppingListScreenViewModel.changeItemChecked(item, isChecked)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (shoppingListScreenViewModel.shoppingListScreenState.value.showAddItemDialog) {
                OnTheFlyAddItemDialog(
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel = shoppingListScreenViewModel,
                    focusManager = focusManager,
                    navController = navController,
                    onDismiss = {
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(name, "")
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(nameError, false)
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(category, "")
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(categoryError, false)
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue("ShowAddItemDialog", false)
                    }
                )
                {
                    scope.launch {
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.addShoppingListItemToDb()
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue("ShowAddItemDialog", false)
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(name, "")
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(nameError, false)
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(category, "")
                        shoppingListScreenViewModel.setStateValue(categoryError, false)
                        // triggerCount++
                    }
                }
            }

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(NavScreens.AddItemScreen.route) {
                        popUpTo(NavScreens.AddItemScreen.route) {
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text("Goto add item screen")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: About the parent container, you should post the relevant code

Comment: I just updated the question with the parent container code.

Answer (score 1):

You set a `contentPadding` in your `LazyColumn` that is responsible for the spaces. Remove it, or set it to zero.

```
LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        vertical = 8.dp,
        horizontal = 0.dp
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding around the `Checkbox` depends on the `minimumTouchTargetSize` defined when the `onClick` is not `null` with a hardcoded value of `48.dp`.

You can override it using:

```
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false,
    ) {
        Checkbox(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),  //4.dp 
            checked = false,
            onCheckedChange = {}
        )
    }
```

but it is not the best choice in term of accessibility.

[image].
[image]

The space around the Row depends on the `contentPadding` defined in the `LazyColumn`.

Comment: I agree with the accessibility warning. I just added some padding around the checkbox with the code you provided.